# what does mysqli_connect() return on successful connection?

Tags: mysqli

What I mean to say is that in the following code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{...}
```

what does

> if(!$con)

represent?Does it mean

> if($con==false)

or it means

> if($con==0)

Comment: yes it means if($con==false)

Comment: thank @YourCommonSense

Answer (score -1):

Well, if it connects then it returns the object

```
Resource # {someNumber}
```

It means connection built.

It should return either `ture` or `Resource # somenumber`.

after that, you need to select database using `mysqli_select_db($con, 'dbName');`

if it returns true, it means database connected. Otherwise not connected

Comment: Updated my answer.